# jquery plugin bind ajax load element

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my jquery code, it's work. But I have a problem, if ajax load a new input, this input not work for my `mylimit`. How to fix it? Thanks.

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.mylimit = function() { 

        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.attr('limit_count') && $this.attr('message')) {
                var limit_count = $this.attr('limit_count');
                var message = $this.attr('message');
                $this.on('keyup', function(){
                    var count = $this.val().length;
                    if(count > limit_count) {
                        alert(message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });  
    };

    $('input').mylimit();

}( jQuery ));
```

## **[JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lighter/BuaY4/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/lighter/BuaY4/16/)**

Comment: Yes, I want to do it, but my code not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Fixes to existing code

You have a number of typing mistakes (e.g. `limit-count` is not one of your attributes and `limit-message` is one). A variable referenced in `count > limit` was `limit` but you called that one `limit_count`:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/BuaY4/13/

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.mylimit = function() { 

        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.attr('limit').length && $this.attr('limit-message').length) {
                var limit = $this.attr('limit');
                var message = $this.attr('limit-message');
                $this.on('keyup', function(){
                    var count = $this.val().length;
                    if(count > limit) {
                        alert(message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });  
    };

    $('input').mylimit();

}( jQuery ));
```

### 2. Handling dynamically loaded content:

You need to work out how you will reference object that will not exist yet. You can either rerun plugins after the Ajax load, or use delegated event handlers (preferred if possible).

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/BuaY4/18/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on("keyup", "input", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr('limit').length && $this.attr('limit-message').length) {
            var limit = $this.attr('limit');
            var message = $this.attr('limit-message');
            console.log("Limit: " + limit);
            var count = $this.val().length;
            if (count > limit) {
                alert(message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This uses a delegated event handler (special variation of `on`). It listens for event bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor (`document` is the default if you do not have one convenient), it *then* applies the jQuery filter, it *then* calls the function *for each matching element that caused the event*.

**Notes:**

- `jQuery(function($){ YOUR CODE HERE });` is a special shortcut that is both a DOM ready event handler and gives you a locally scoped `$` variable. Very handy :)
- There is no need to implement this functionality as a plugin (e.g. as `$.fn.mylimit =` as that cannot be applied to dynamically loaded content (which you requested). Just include the code and it will apply to all input that have your attributes.

Comment: @LLL: Now try the new code for working on all input (even after dynamic loading)

Comment: I know this method, could I implement on the `jquery.fn` ?

Comment: @LLL: You would not implement it as a plugin as it applies to all inputs (then looks for the `limit` attributes to decide if to apply the rules). This is the only way it will work. Making it a plugin is a waste of time. Just include the code shown and it will work.

Comment: Ok, and I have question, I have used `jquery placeholder`, but that work for me, when I use jquery append a new input, how to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57476/discussion-between-lll-and-trueblueaussie).

Comment: Thanks a million. I got it suddenly.